# QField does not open Raster.gpkg?

Tags: geopackage, qfield

Qfield cannot load GeoPackage raster data exported with Qgis 3.8.0.  Download vector data from the gpkg file.  The test with a single raster file in a GeoPackage also failed.

Comment: Achtung, es folgt Werbung: Schau dir bitte mal [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) an für solche Fälle. - Attention, advertisement: Please have a look at DeepL.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason qfield does not understand relative path in .gpkg rasters. My workaround was to create exactly same path of qfield project in my Linux machine (/sdcard/Android/data...). Might it be same case for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you drag and drop the geopackage raster from a file browser into QGIS (and not open it from internally), this helps to store the path as a relative path inside the QGIS project file.

Comment: i have the same problem, your solution did not work unfortunately (i drag&dropped the rasterpics from QGIS browser into the layer overview but it did not change anything :/ )

Comment: Can you try doing that from a "file browser" instead of the QGIS browser?

Comment: i dropped the gpkg containing two orthophotos and a point layer from windows file explorer into qgis layer control, with same result. when i want to export that project, it says several layers are not configured, when i go to configure the (QField) project, i have only the options "no action" and "remove" for the orthophotos

Comment: And what happens if you do "no action"?

Comment: when i open the .qgs file with a text editor, it saves the full path (and not the relative one). another difference i observed is that it is using a different seperator for the layer. the working (point layer) goes:  (...).gpkg|layername=(...)   the non working raster goes: (...)gpkg:Orthofoto1"

Comment: if i leave it with "no action" and sync the project, i get the usual error

Comment: Please clarify "usual"

Comment: By the way, the "full path" issue is exactly the one that we were once able to work around with the drag and drop. I'm surprised this is broken too meanwhile.

Comment: the usual error is " the following layers could not be loaded"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97585/discussion-between-sn1ks-and-matthias-kuhn).